# Mouse events not fired after changing the parent of a frame

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe

I'm changing the parent of a frame a runtime to move the frame from one form to another. That works fine but after that my components do not receive mouse events any longer. For example, `CM_MOUSEENTER` and `CM_MOUSELEAVE` is not fired.

```
Frame.Parent := SecondDisplayForm;
Frame.Align := alClient;
SecondDisplayForm.Show;
```

I don't understand this effect and I don't really know what information to provide, so if you have hints please help me out here.

Comment: Does your other form have KeyPreview set to true?

Comment: `KeyPreview` should not affect mouse events.

Comment: +1 I have the same problem, very annoying. In my case I changed the parent after CM_MOUSEENTER and before CM_MOUSELEAVE fired. Maybe this is important too..

Comment: @balazs: yes that is true for me too. The mouse is over the component when I change the parent.

Comment: Warning: Handle parent replacement carefully! You have to take ownership into account. See: [How to detach a panel and show it in a separate window?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6461820/757830)

Comment: @NGLN: thanks. In my case, this is only temporary and parent is always reset before ownership can come into play, so this is not an issue

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use a `TFrame` instead of a `TPanel`?

Comment: @Remy yes, same problem. Actually, I have a frame. Sorry if that confused you. I edited the question to make it more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in D7 as NGLN reported, but in BDS2006 it's reproducible. I found that it's important to change the parent after the `cm_mouseenter`, and before `cm_mouseleave`, otherways ther's no problem. The problem is in the controls.pas I think, maybe it's a bug. Playing around a little bit I found out that if you `Perform` a `wm_mouseleave` message before changing the parent everything is fine again.

In my sample code i change the parent in an onclick event.

```
  TFrame3 = class(TFrame)
    procedure FrameClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure CMMouseEnter( var msg: TMessage ); message CM_MOUSEENTER;
    procedure CMMouseLeave( var msg: TMessage ); message CM_MOUSELEAVE;
  public
  end;

implementation

procedure TFrame3.CMMouseEnter(var msg: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  Color := clRed;
end;

procedure TFrame3.CMMouseLeave(var msg: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  Color := clBlue;
end;

procedure TFrame3.FrameClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
if parent = Form1 then
  begin
    Perform( WM_MOUSELEAVE, 0, 0 );
    parent := Form2;
    align := alClient;
    Form1.Hide;
    Form2.Show;
  end else
  begin
    Perform( WM_MOUSELEAVE, 0, 0 );
    parent := Form1;
    align := alClient;
    Form2.Hide;
    Form1.Show;
  end;
end;
```

I think the problem is related to the FMouseControl in Controls.pas, but haven't investigated it properly.

Comment: +1 Thanks. That's very helpful and confirms my assumption. The workaround with the `CM_MOUSELEAVE` message is a bit hard to get to work because the parent is changed from the outside, not from the inside (triggered by a key event processed in the main form's `OnKeyDown` handler).

Comment: You should trigger a WM_MOUSELEAVE message NOT a CM_MOUSELEAVE! I think it should work in your case too, because you can call Frame.Perform(WM_MOUSELEAVE, 0, 0 ) from anywhere, or you can override the setparent of the frame and put this code there maybe with some check if there was a mouseenter.